# Oracle Apex HTML CSS Inserting Vertical Line between two sub regions

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to place a vertical line between two sub-regions? I guess what I would do before is create a wrapper for the items I wanted to divide, split them up into divs, then add a css separator between the two. I don't really know how to do that in Apex.

I'm currently using oracle 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put the following code into Page's Inline CSS property:

```
@media all and (min-width: 100px)
{
  .right-border{
    border-right: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

Then, for the "left" subregion, put `right-border` into the "CSS classes" property.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! that was super helpful